# WPF Style Expander header as GroupBox header (wpf theme)

Tags: wpf, styles, themes, expander, groupbox

I can't figure out how to apply groupbox header style to expander header.
I'm using WPF Themes, specifically BureauBlue.

Now expander and group boxes look like this:

[image]

I'd like them to look the same! I tried to restyle with blend as explained [here](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/28/wpf-making-a-expander-look-like-a-groupbox/) with no success

Comment: Please post what you tried. Or some screenshots how it will look like.

Comment: edited with screenshot